# When is a question for resources/references in Q&A format?

Tags: discussion, scope, question-quality, cstheory, close-reasons

I am puzzled if it is appropriate to ask for resources/referemces for good exercises for an introductory TCS course. I personally think that this is a very precise question, but I see the danger that the answers might depend very much on everyone's personal opinion, which might lead to an open-ended discussion. Also I noticed that related questions such as

[List of intro TCS books for those who don't know much about TCS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/454/list-of-intro-tcs-books-for-those-who-dont-know-much-about-tcs)

were closed.

Nevertheless, I would really like to know about this. And I can imagine that other users are interested in this as well.

Also, let me know if cs.SE is the right place for this question or should I post it in cstheory.SE. Since I consider the question as non-research-question I would prefer to post it in cs.SE.

Comment: I think you can get many good ideas for exercises just by looking at the questions already posted.

Comment: @Raphael: I agree, there are nice exercises on this page. But actually not that many of the type I would ask in a TCS introductory course. Also: most of them have answers. I would definitely like to have more resources for easy problems.

Comment: What I just [found](https://twitter.com/neeldhara): [TrueShelf](http://www.trueshelf.com/), a crowd-driven exercise repository (without answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List questions are a problem for the platform because ranking answers does not make a lot of sense. We have not definitely decided yet how to treat them (see [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-about-list-questions) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/145/98)) -- different sites have different policies -- but the tendency seems to be that we don't want them (maybe because they don't know how to deal with them).

Therefore, I think you should not post the question as proposed (and certainly not on cstheory). If the [Educators proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23685/educators?referrer=KIYoBIrhRH8gzQ7ReguWpg2) goes live, maybe it will be the place for such question.

You *could*, however, set up your own resource (a wiki?) for this purpose, which would be great and useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading the discussions on meta you have mentioned, I have to say that the current policy is confusing. I decided not to post my question. However I would appreciate it, if there is a clear policy, approved by the community.

Comment: @A.Schulz I completely agree. However, you need a certain amount of community to make a policy. At the time, we did not have it here; just look at the participation on the questions. The latest [homework chapter](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/468/homework-policy) went down reasonably well, so we might try again. If you have a good idea how list questions can be handled (I don't), you are very welcome to open up a new thread.