# Reference answers to frequently asked questions

Tags: discussion, faq, questions

## Why am I here?

If you were sent here, somebody thought that you posted your question too early, that is you don't know facts and/or techniques one would learn in undergraduate courses. This is not your fault, but for us who write answers it has become a chore to explain the same things over and over again (many such questions arise from homework, and homework problems do not differ a lot).

Therefore, we would like you to go over your course material again (if you are a student) or peruse material readily available in libraries or the web. Chances are you will be able to answer or at least improve your question with your new knowledge!

In order to help you with that, we have compiled a list of questions that are of general nature and have answers that should apply in a variety of situations. Please take the time to browse through those relevant to your question; chances are that we already have you covered. If not, it is likely that one of two things has happend:

1. You don't understand the reference material.
   In this case, the best response is to do further research. That includes picking up textbooks (the reference answers may list some) and asking focused questions on the [main site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).
2. You understand the material, but you can not apply it to your situation.
   In this case, edit your old question to include your attempts at solving the problem and why they failed. Then flag it for reopening; with this new information, we can help you identify your specific problem and move forward.

Remember: "I don't understand any of this, please explain in plain English!" is a bad enquiry. Nobody can know what your problem really is, which factoid would help you understand, and what the required scope for a good answer is. Try instead to phrase questions like "In above proof, why does B follow from A?" or "I have an algorithm but it seems to be wrong for corner case X, how can I fix it?"

That said, you find links to the reference posts grouped by topic below:

- [Formal languages](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/843/98)
- [Complexity theory](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/845/98)
- [Algorithms and their analysis](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/844/98)
- [Asymptotics](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/846/98)
- [Computability](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/847/98)
- [Architecture](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/848/98)
- [Operating Systems](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/867/7459)
- [Mathematics](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/849/98)

Comment: In order to keep this question as clean as possible, I'll protect it. If you think discussion is necessary, please open new thread and/or visit us in [chat], where I'll also accept nominations for new/other reference questions.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/717/98) for a discussion about which questions are suited to become reference questions, and whether we should use a tag to label them.

Comment: see also [what is computer science](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/231/what-is-computer-science)

Comment: this question collects many popular/standard [CS refs](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/874/reference-answer-for-textbooks-in-subfields-other-than-algorithms)

Comment: Should this include machine models, say, RAM & Turing?

Comment: @greybeard With which (types of) questions? (Please come to [chat] for discussing this.)

Answer (score 10):

[Why have I been sent here?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/98)

### Formal Languages

- [What is the difference between an algorithm, a language and a problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem)
- [Are there other ways to describe formal languages other than grammars?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/813/are-there-other-ways-to-describe-formal-languages-other-than-grammars)
- [How to show that L = L(G)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11315/how-to-show-that-l-lg)
- [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)
- [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular)
- [What's wrong with my pumping lemma proof?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/44994) (You must show that every partition $w=xyz$ fails, not just one.)
- [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions)
- [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)
- [How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free/)
- [Language theoretic comparison of LL and LR grammars](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43/language-theoretic-comparison-of-ll-and-lr-grammars)

Answer (score 7):

[Why have I been sent here?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/98)

### Complexity Theory

- [What is the difference between an algorithm, a language and a problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem)
- [How can we assume that basic operations on numbers take constant time?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time)
- [What is the definition of $P$, $NP$, $NP$-complete and $NP$-hard?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/in-basic-terms-what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard/)
- [Optimization version of decision problems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/939/optimization-version-of-decision-problems)
  [Decision problems vs "real" problems that aren't yes-or-no](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/473/decision-problems-vs-real-problems-that-arent-yes-or-no)
- [What are common techniques for reducing problems to each other?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other)
- [How not to solve P=NP?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/how-not-to-solve-p-np)
- [Dealing with intractability: NP-complete problems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/dealing-with-intractability-np-complete-problems)
- [Why nondeterminism?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88403/why-nondeterminism)

Answer (score 5):

[Why have I been sent here?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/98)

### Algorithms

- [What is the difference between an algorithm, a language and a problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem)
- [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)
- [How to come up with the runtime of algorithms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/192/how-to-come-up-with-the-runtime-of-algorithms)
- [Explaining the relevance of asymptotic complexity of algorithms to practice of designing algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/explaining-the-relevance-of-asymptotic-complexity-of-algorithms-to-practice-of-d)
  [Justification for neglecting constants in Big O](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/justification-for-neglecting-constants-in-big-o)
- [How do O and Ω relate to worst and best case?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-relate-to-worst-and-best-case)
- [How can we assume that basic operations on numbers take constant time?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-can-we-assume-that-basic-operations-on-numbers-take-constant-time)
- [Differences and relationships between randomized and nondeterministic algorithms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/5008/differences-and-relationships-between-randomized-and-nondeterministic-algorithms)

Answer (score 4):

[Why have I been sent here?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/98)

### Asymptotics

- [What does the "big O complexity" of a function mean?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/88577/98)
- [How does one know which notation of time complexity analysis to use?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use)
- [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)
  (Also: [Algorithmic intuition for logarithmic complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/581/intuition-for-logarithmic-complexity/))
- [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)
- [How do O and Ω relate to worst and best case?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case)

Answer (score 4):

[Why have I been sent here?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/98)

### Computability

- [What is the difference between an algorithm, a language and a problem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem)
- [Why nondeterminism?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88403/why-nondeterminism)
- [Are there minimum criteria for a programming language being Turing complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/991/are-there-minimum-criteria-for-a-programming-language-being-turing-complete)
- [How to show that a function is not computable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11181/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-computable)
- [What are common techniques for reducing problems to each other?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other)
- [Differences and relationships between randomized and nondeterministic algorithms?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/5008/differences-and-relationships-between-randomized-and-nondeterministic-algorithms)

Answer (score 3):

[Why have I been sent here?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/98)

### Architecture

- [How does a computer work?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/how-does-a-computer-work)
- [How does the computer determine whether a number is smaller or greater than another?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/how-does-the-computer-determine-whether-a-number-is-smaller-or-greater-than-anot)
- [Tag, index and offset of associative cache](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33818/tag-index-and-offset-of-associative-cache)

Answer (score 3):

### Operating Systems

<sup>We need some filler text until we have more questions or SE will automatically delete the answer.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[Why have I been sent here?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/98)

### Mathematics

- [How do I write a proof using induction on the length of the input string?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/how-do-i-write-a-proof-using-induction-on-the-length-of-the-input-string)
  <sup>Provides a general introduction to induction.</sup>
- [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)